# How can I return a value into the main program when calling a function with a keyboard event in TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to play around with tkinter and keyboard input events. How can I develop the code below so that when a key is pressed (eg up arrow), a function is called that increments some global variables (x and y of the position of a canvas shape) by 1 so that (for example) a canvas shape can move around the screen? Obviously what I have below calls a function that changes local x. How can I return a value from it into the main program? Any help would be extremely valued. Thanks

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10

a = 100
b = 100

def change_coord(event):
    x = x+1


window = Tk()

window.geometry("500x500")

canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 400, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

coord = x, y, a, b
arc = canvas1.create_arc(coord, start=0, extent=150, fill="blue")

window.bind_all('<Up>', change_coord)

window.mainloop()
```

So here is a workaround of sorts...

```
from tkinter import *

x = 50
y = 10

a = 200
b = 100

def change_coord(event):
    global x
    x = x+1
    coord = x, y, a, b
    arc = canvas1.create_arc(coord, start=0, extent=150, fill="blue")

window = Tk()

window.geometry("500x500")

canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 400, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)



window.bind_all('<Up>', change_coord)

window.mainloop()
```

But I would ideally like the shape to appear when the program is run and not when the key is pressed. So the canvas draw code needs to be placed in the main. How can I pass the updated x values out of the function so that it can update the coordinates of the canvas draw?
I would love some help here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the coordinates using `canvas1.coords(arc, ...)`.

If you make a list og `coord` like `coord = [x, y, a, b]`, you can update it in your event function with `coord[0] +=1` and update the coordinates with `canvas1.coords(arc, *coord)`. The `*` automatically unpacks the list into the four arguments that define the coordinates.
If you do this you will also have to put the `*` before `coord` when creating the arc.
The advantage of having your coordinates in a list is that you can change the values, tuples are immutable.

Here's an example which lets you move the arc around the canvas

```
from tkinter import *

x = 10
y = 10
a = 100
b = 100

def change_coord(event):
    global coord
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        coord[1] -=1
        coord[3] -=1
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        coord[1] +=1
        coord[3] +=1
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        coord[0] +=1
        coord[2] +=1
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        coord[0] -=1
        coord[2] -=1
    canvas1.coords(arc, *coord)

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

canvas1=Canvas(window, height = 400, width = 400)
canvas1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
coord = [x, y, a, b]
arc = canvas1.create_arc(*coord, start=0, extent=150, fill="blue")

window.bind_all('<Up>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Down>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Left>', change_coord)
window.bind_all('<Right>', change_coord)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This sounds great. Thank you. I know I am being cheeky here but would you mind posting an example? Thank you for your time.